# What does it mean the sum of two sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Considering the Second Isomorphism Theorem for rings:

> Let $I$ be a subring of a ring $R$ and $J$ an ideal of $R$. Then $I∩J$ is an ideal of $I$ and $$I/I∩J \cong (I+J)/J;$$

1- How the sum of two ideals (i.e. $I+J$) is defined?

and

2- How the sum of two set in general is defined if it differs from the answer of the question 1?

The definition $(r+I)(s+I)=(rs+I)$ also doesn't help. And, I know what $a+I$ means.

Comment: it is sum of ideals, not rings.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - the second question is regarding set theory.

Comment: No, it's not...

Answer (score 1):

$I + J = \{i+j: i \in I, j \in J\}$

Comment: Is this definition for any sets including ideals, rings, groups, ... ? Thank you

Comment: This definition is pretty standard in any context where you have a binary operation denoted $+$.